# How to Replicate Cloud PostgreSQL into BigQuery using Data Fusion

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have Cloud PostgreSQL database that changes(Create,Update) continuously. So I'm trying way that Replicate my database tables into BigQuery Tables using cloud Data Fusion. So the the CDC (Change Data Capture) should update the BigQuery as according to the change in PostgreSQL.
https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/replication

1. Replicating data from MySQL to BigQuery
2. Replicating data from SQL Server to BigQuery
3. Replicating data from Oracle DB to BigQuery

Can we have the same method for "**from Cloud PostgreSQL to BigQuery**"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best for your use case would be to take advantage of the database migration service.

PostgreSQL is supported and you can set a "continuous" migration job, to have a CDC-like replication service

https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/quickstart